# Cannot switch to Holo Dark theme

Tags: android

I'm making an app which would look cool with the Holo Dark theme.
I've set the XML to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

It still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you set your AppTheme style in the Manifest?

Comment: And it still defaults to Holo Light....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you have this declared in **values-v14/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

Comment: Oh... yes. values-v14/ is what I had to do. Thanks!

Comment: That is strange, because my app has min API 14. But it still needs the Holo styles to be put in v14. Anyway, it works. 10x